# FDIR Configuration to forward packets to a queue not working as expected

Tags: linux, linux-networking, drivers

Currently, I am working on to modify Intel i40e network card driver.

I am trying a simple thing using FDIR to forward a specified set of UDP packets to a particular queue of the NIC via ethtool as:

```
# enable ntuple for both ports
ethtool -K ens1f0 ntuple on
ethtool -K ens1f1 ntuple on

ethtool -U ens1f0 flow-type udp4 src-port 1111 dst-port 319 action 3
ethtool -U ens1f1 flow-type udp4 src-port 1111 dst-port 319 action 3
```

Also, I have set the smp_affinity of two interrupts as:

```
echo 0200 >> /proc/irq/57/smp_affinity
echo 0400 >> /proc/irq/88/smp_affinity
```

To verify my configuration, I checked this behavior using /proc/interrupts. The output of /proc/interrupts is as:

[Output of /proc/interrupts for two NICs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKURM.png)

I am not sure if I missed a significant step here. Any help would be appreciated.